# regex java: how to replace a string in a generic between the start tag and end tag of a generic

Tags: java, regex, tags

In java, I have a string like so:

```
"bla bla bla bla [BACK] bla bla bla [bla bla [GO] bla bla bla bla [bla"
```

and I want to find a rule with the regex to replace start tag "[" with "(start)" and the end tag "]" with "(end)".

A "start-tag or an end tag alone" should be ignored.

The result is that I would get the following:

```
bla bla bla bla (start)BACK(end) bla bla bla [ bla bla (start)GO(end) bla bla bla bla [bla
```

Comment: Is there any rule that says what exactly is allowed between start and end tags (besides that brackets are obviously not allowed there)?

Answer (score 5):

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll(
    "(?x)       # Turn on verbose mode                    \n" +
    "\\[        # Match a [                               \n" +
    "(          # Match and capture in group 1:           \n" +
    "[^\\[\\]]* # Any number of characters except brackets\n" +
    ")          # End of capturing group                  \n" +
    "\\]        # Match a ]", "(start)$1(end)");
```

will match/replace only balanced `[`/`]` pairs with no brackets in-between them.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, why are you ignoring the first bracket? Anyway, [here](http://regexr.com?34s8h) is the regex.

js: `'bla bla bla bla [BACK] bla bla bla [bla bla [GO] bla bla bla bla [bla'.replace(new RegExp(/\[([^\[\]]+?)\]/g),'(start)$1(end)')`

result: `"bla bla bla bla (start)BACK(end) bla bla bla [bla bla (start)GO(end) bla bla bla bla [bla"`